# RabbitMQ LVC is giving all messages

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

So i installed the RabbitMQ plugin https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-lvc-plugin and i'm using in c#, sending the same value through the exchange and everytime that the subscriber is up he receives all the messages, and if i keep sending the same message my consumer will get, i don't know if this is how it's suppose to works but i assume that i would just get the last message, is there anything wrong with what i am doing or i did not understood how it works?
Publisher Code:

```
        var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=brw20028419,brw20028414").Advanced;
        var exchange = bus.ExchangeDeclare("lvc", "x-lvc");
        var routingKey = "lvcTest";

        ThreadStart start = () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    var messageS = new Message<string>("value");
                    bus.Publish(exchange, routingKey, false, false, messageS);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
        };
        var thread = new Thread(start);
        thread.Start();
```

Consumer Code:

```
        var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=brw20028419,brw20028414").Advanced;
        var exchange = bus.ExchangeDeclare("lvc", "x-lvc");
        var queue = bus.QueueDeclare("q");
        bus.Bind(exchange, queue, "lvcTest");

        Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages. " +
                          "To exit press CTRL+C");
        bus.Consume(queue, (body, properties, info) => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            var routingKey = info.RoutingKey;
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received '{0}':'{1}'",
                               routingKey, message);
        }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "and everytime that the subscriber is up he receives all the messages, and if i keep sending the same message my consumer will get"

as stated in the readme of the project

> "The last value exchange acts like a direct exchange"

so this is the expected behaviour.

The only difference with a direct exchange, is that the lvc exchange keeps track of last message for each routing key, so when a new queue is bond to the exchange with a specific binding key, last message published to the exchange with a routing key equal to the binding key (which was stored in cache) is sent to the newly added queue.

To understand, you could change your producer code to send only one message once a first consumer is bond to your exchange. Then bind a second consumer to your exchange, with same binding key, and even if your producer do not send any new message, the second consumer will get the same message than the first consumer, since it has been cached by the lvc exchange.

Comment: Oh, i get it! but if i want something to give me only the difference i should implement in one of the sides right? Or does a solution like that exists? Say that i receive all the time the same value and at tn the value changes, i just want to receive the first and the value changed.

Comment: I do not think there is any plugin that fits your purpose in RMQ. I guess you should implement this on the publisher side.